# Converting time series data to MNIST like data?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

There are some time series data like this:

```
Time    Feature A     Feature B       Class
1          0.3           0.6            1
2          0.5           -0.2           0
3          0.8           0.3            1
...
```

When using RNN on MNIST, we can use 28 time steps of 28 rows as input. For these time series data, one could use 10 time steps of rows for the classification problem. (eg. Feed the rows from `T1 to T10` one by one into the RNN to predict the class at `T11`, then the rows from `T2 to T11` to predict `T12` and so on.)

What is some way to convert the time series data to build an array of arrays?

Comment: Hey, Hendo welcome to Stackoverflow, I read through your question but was unable to understand your question, Could you please add some description probably simple to explain your question?

Comment: Indeed, the MNIST data set has no temporal element nor natural sequence. It's not clear what the goal is as MNIST is already naturally represented as 2d arrays.

Comment: Wrong, i any is extremely clear. Just you wrongx, can't understand, idts.